# Button interacting with trapdoor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I was making a chair that has trapdoors. I have a button that is supposed to power redstone behind a block but powers the trapdoor and the door of this chair. Tutorial:

I don't want that because always I press that button, I have to close the trapdoors manually.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Could you post a screenshot of your setup perhaps?

Comment: [Click to see the screenshot](http://gavitex.com/share/l0pw7p2tx)

Comment: The button of the screenshot powers the trapdoor and the door of the chair and I don't want that. How do I do?

Comment: Ok. How about editing the screenshot into the question?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a screenshot at the link.

Comment: Voting to reopen. I tried to edit the screenshot into the question, but I failed. I tried again, this time successfully, so this is no longer unclear.

Comment: I voted an answer correct because it works but not in my case being that it still hapening by another thing that I have there.
Now my objective is to find a non conductive block. All the answers on Internet didn't worked for me. If there's not, I want to now if there's another thing like a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the button 1 block upward and it should stop interacting with the trapdoor.

If you can't do that, consider a substitute that doesn't interact with redstone. 1 example is a sign.